# Distributing a proprietary library that uses an LGPL library

Tags: lgpl, commercial

I would like to create a JAVA library, that will use an LGPL library. The LGPL library is a library that provides an API to create charts, whereas my library will provide a more high level API like creating a Window with a chart inside it. For example, I could have the following:

```
Proprietary windowWithChart = CreateWindowChart();
LGPLChart chart = windowWidthChart.getChart();
```

If I distribute my library as a JAR, is it mandatory to use an LGPL license, or can I use a proprietary license ? I'm wondering if my work could be considered as "a work using the LGPL library", or "a work based on the LGPL library"

Comment: What do you mean with "use" exactly? Have you read the LGPL license and know what your obligations are when you distribute work which makes use of LGPL-licensed libraries and the difference to actually directly incorporating its code into your project in a way that it is not used as library any longer?

Comment: "use" means my code is instantiating classes from the LGPL library. I want to distribute my library as a .jar, that doesn't contain the source code of the LPGL library. To use my library, you will need both my library .jar and the LGPL library. And Yes, I read the LGPL text, that is not clear at 100% to me (a software developer).

Comment: Does the JAR file you are shipping contain any code of the library you are "using" or must the LGPL library be installed as separate JAR file?

Comment: It must be installed as a separate JAR file. I haven't copied any line of code from it.